# display div only on small screen

Tags: javascript, if-statement, document.write

I'm trying to only display the following code on a small screen:

```
<div align="center"><a href="/mobile/mobile_home.asp">Mobile Site</a></div>
```

So the full code is:

```
<script>
<!-- if (screen.width <= 699){
 document.write("<div align=\"center\"><a href=\"/mobile/mobile_home.asp\">Mobile Site</a></div>")}
//-->
</script>
```

If I just do the below, it works.

```
<script>
<!-- document.write("<div align=\"center\"><a href=\"/mobile/mobile_home.asp\">Mobile Site</a></div>")}
//-->
</script>
```

Apparently, I have some syntax or something wrong with the if statement. Or is there a simpler way of doing this? Little help. Thanks.

Comment: are you really trying it on a small screen or just in a small (resized) window? You might try `window` instead of `screen`

Comment: testing on my phone. <!-- if (window.width() <= 699){
 document.write("<div align=\"center\"><a href=\"/mobile/mobile_home.asp\">Mobile Site</a></div>")}
//--> does not work.

Comment: actually its 
var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;

in pure javscript

Answer (score 1):

You could use a media query in your css:  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

HTML:

```
 <div class="mobileOnly">mobile site link</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.mobileOnly
{
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 699px)
{
  div.mobileOnly
  {
    display: block;
  }

}
```

And don't forget the viewport meta tag in your head tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

Comment: I tried this method but for some reason it does not display the div when being viewed on my phone. I'm using classic asp if that makes a difference.

Comment: you may also need the viewport meta tag:  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (window.innerWidth <= 699){
 document.write("<div align=\"center\"><ahref=\"/mobile/mobile_home.asp\">MobileSite</a></div>")
}
```

A cross-browser solution (using clientWidth and clientHeight for IE8 and earlier):

```
var w = window.innerWidth
|| document.documentElement.clientWidth
|| document.body.clientWidth;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use @media queries for that .

```
 <div align="center" id="mobileSite"><a href="/mobile/mobile_home.asp">Mobile Site</a></div>

    <style>  
      @media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 699) {
      #mobileSite { display: block; }  
    }

      @media screen and (min-width: 700) and (max-width: 1024px) {
      #mobileSite { display: none; }  
    }

  </style>
```